# Converting Lat & Long values received from GPS tracker

Tags: php, gps, latitude-longitude

I have created an application that will listen to a particular port in which a GPS tracker will send data to it.

There's not much support received from the company(Chinese) whom I bought the GPS tracker, for development purpose. So it's kind of tougher to grasp everything myself.

I was able to figure out most of the data that was sent from the GPS tracker. The only thing is, the location coordinates sent from the tracker is in some specific format which I think it needs to be converted.

It's something like this:

```
1234N07700
7689E000
```

(the above values are just sample)

So am having trouble in converting it to actual Lat & Long values. I tried searching in Google, but couldn't find any examples based on this. Maybe my search terms where wrong!

Atleast if the name of the format used to represent this coordinates is known, I would be able to do further research.

Any ideas? Thank you.

---

**EDIT**

Example of a full string received from the gps tracker:
[image]

Comment: There are GPS formats that are compressed and needs some serious math to decode.

Comment: @Andreas, Oh okay. Any suggestions regarding the above one?

Comment: No, sorry... What is the expected output in lat/lon?

Comment: @Andreas, what am trying to figure out is the lat & long in decimal format. Say something like: x.xxxx, x.xxxxx

Comment: I know... But the numbers you posted must mean something that you know. I.E. You "pushed the button" at one point to get the output above. Where on this planet were you then?

Comment: @Andreas, sorry it's the location of my home. I do not wish to make my home's location co-ordinates to be public, by posting it here. That's why I posted a dummy data as example.

Comment: Ok... Fair enough. It would be a lot easier to have a expected output when you look at something. So can you create a new location code that we can look at? However... from your output posted, I think you live close to me. Correct?

Comment: @Andreas, The lat and long values I posted in the question is a manipulated one(but the length of the data is same). I mean it's not the real one that I got from the gps tracker. Because if the real data is posted here, I fear it would be misused by others or bots or something. To post a real data, I have to take my GPS tracker to somewhere else and check the readings. Also, am not located anywhere near you. Am in India. Thank you

Comment: Great! You manipulated GPS data so that we can't help you. :thumbs up: for you!

Comment: @Andreas, when I said manipulated, I meant I replaced the values that I highlighted in yellow color(in my screenshot) with the values "12345...". I mean I changed the exact data as I don't think it should be made visible to the public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this website: http://www.sunearthtools.com/dp/tools/conversion.php

You will be able to see this format:

```
GPS: ddmm.mmmm[N,S]ddmm.mmmm[E,W] (Dec Min)
```

So I guess the location coordinate values starts right after the `A` in your screenshot and all the way till the `E`.

Based on your screenshot, the location would be `0829.1234N07700.5678E`

**Now for the latitude calculation part,**

```
Consider 0829.1234N,
Take first two digits, and then divide the rest of the digits by 60 and add them together.
ie, Latitude = 08 + 29.1234/60 = 8.48539
```

If the last character was `S` instead of `N`, put negative sign to the result.

**Now for the longitude calculation part,**

```
Consider 07700.5678E,
Take first three digits, and then divide the rest of the digits by 60 and add them together.
ie, Longitude = 077 + 00.5678/60 = 77.009463
```

If the last character was `W` instead of `E`, put negative sign to the result.